# django-ajax-selects inline 'add another' won't bind

Tags: django-admin, django-ajax-selects

I am using django 1.6 admin-panel with [django-suit](http://djangosuit.com/), and I am trying to make a tabular inline that will auto-complete me with a name of a model instance. 
For this I use [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects).
Now, if I define, let's say, `extra = 3`, then I will have 3 tabular lines bound with ajax.

And every other line I add with the 'Add another line' button won't auto-complete me (the widget is shown. Its just that the ajax is not bound to the field).

Is there a django-ajax-select option that will bind the new fields in the inline? I saw in the documentation that one of its features was 'Admin inlines', but no materialistic example of how to do it.

If django-ajax-selects does not offer a built-in way to achieve it, how can it be done with jQuery/ Javascript overriding?

Here's my **inlines.py**

```py
class AlternativeInline(AjaxSelectAdminTabularInline):
    model = Alternative
    form = make_ajax_form(Alternative, {'item_compared_to': 'item'})
    fk_name = 'item_compared_with'
    suit_classes = 'suit-tab suit-tab-alternatives'
    verbose_name = 'Alternative'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Alternatives'
    extra = 1
```

If any other snippets from my code are required, just say so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solved this problem all by myself.
Documented it in django-ajax-selects GitHub.
Link's [here](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects/issues/87).